# Range based for loop for linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, linked-list, iterator

I have a function which operates on a nested linked list. The function is the following:

```
void DoLiana(void) {

    PlotPointer plot;
    TreePointer tree;

        plot = FirstPlot;
        while (plot != nullptr) {
            tree = plot->FirstTree;
            while (tree != nullptr) {
                if (tree->isLiana) {
                    if (tree->attachedTree == nullptr && TestForLianaAttach(plot, tree))
                    DoLianaAttachement(plot, tree);
                }
                tree = tree->next;
            }
            plot = plot->next;
        }    
}
```

Because this type of iterations happen multiple times in my code I am looking for a way to make the iteration more compact and expressive. I read that in C++11 there are ranged based for loops that iterate over a set. Would this construct be applicable in this situation? Or are there other possible ways to perform these iterations?

Comment: The range based for loop is mostly syntactic sugar and requires that you have a begin / end (more details [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)). So you just need to provide the required interface somehow.

Comment: range-for loop can iterate over anything that provides a pair of iterators. So, make your class support iteration. Or, just use `std::list` or `std::slist` for your linked-list needs - these classes already provide the necessary scaffolding.

Comment: It should be no problem. You need to provide `begin` and `end` method to your container, which would return object with `operator++()` and `operator==` defined. I think a simple pointer fits the bill. @IgorTandetnik I don't think the type returned by begin/end even needs to be an iterator formally.

Comment: But you could immediately use vanilla loops here: `for (PlotPointer plot = FirstPlot; plot != nullptr; plot=plot.next) { for (TreePointer tree = plot->FirstTree, tree!= nullptr; tree=tree->next) { ... }}`

Comment: @luk32 I'm not sure that a *simple pointer* would fit the bill: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74609/custom-iterator-for-a-linked-list-class

Comment: @Bob__ Oh, yeah. Brainfart. Thanks for correction. The storage for linked list quite possible won't be contiguous, so the `++` on pointer wouldn't work. Then it makes a really nice exercise for rolling out an iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can define the appropriate functions for this.

Since oyu have given very few details. Lets make some assumptions.

```
struct Tree
{
    bool  isLiana;
    void* attachedTree;
    Tree* next;
};

using TreePointer = Tree*;

struct Plot
{
    TreePointer FirstTree;
    Plot*       next;
};

using PlotPointer = Plot*;

bool TestForLianaAttach(PlotPointer, TreePointer);
void DoLianaAttachement(PlotPointer, TreePointer);

PlotPointer FirstPlot;
```

To make this work with pointers you need to define the appropriate `begin()` and `end()` methods for your pointers.

```
NextIterator<Plot> begin(PlotPointer ptr)  {return make_NextIterator(ptr);}
NextIterator<Plot> end(PlotPointer)        {return make_NextIterator<Plot>();}

NextIterator<Tree> begin(TreePointer ptr)  {return make_NextIterator(ptr);}
NextIterator<Tree> end(TreePointer)        {return make_NextIterator<Tree>();}
```

The range based for looks for `begin()` and `end()` functions that can be used with your type. Now the standard has default `std::begin()` and `std::end()` that call the `begin()` and `end()` methods on the objects passed. But you can provide your own (like the above) to do a special case for your type/pointer.

Now since your pointers use `p = p->next;` to advance we need an iterator object that does this part of the work. In the above code I have called this `NextIterator`. It is relatively easy to define.

```
template<typename T>
struct NextIterator
{
    T* p;

    NextIterator():       p(nullptr) {}
    NextIterator(T* ptr): p(ptr)     {}

    NextIterator& operator++(){p = p->next;return *this;}

    T const& operator*() const  {return *p;}
    T&       operator*()        {return *p;}
    T const* operator->() const {return p;}
    T*       operator->()       {return p;}

    bool operator==(NextIterator const& rhs) const {return p == rhs.p;}
    bool operator!=(NextIterator const& rhs) const {return p != rhs.p;}
};
template<typename T>
NextIterator<T> make_NextIterator(T* val)   {return NextIterator<T>(val);}
template<typename T>
NextIterator<T> make_NextIterator()         {return NextIterator<T>{};}
```

Now we can re-write your loops using the range based for.

```
void DoLianaRange(void) {

        for(auto& plot: FirstPlot) {
            for(auto& tree: plot.FirstTree) {
                if (tree.isLiana) {
                    if (tree.attachedTree == nullptr && TestForLianaAttach(&plot, &tree))
                    DoLianaAttachement(&plot, &tree);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Original version for comparison.

```
void DoLiana(void) {

    PlotPointer plot;
    TreePointer tree;

        plot = FirstPlot;
        while (plot != nullptr) {
            tree = plot->FirstTree;
            while (tree != nullptr) {
                if (tree->isLiana) {
                    if (tree->attachedTree == nullptr && TestForLianaAttach(plot, tree))
                    DoLianaAttachement(plot, tree);
                }
                tree = tree->next;
            }
            plot = plot->next;
        }
}
```

Or you could simply use the standard for loop!!

```
void DoLianaForLoop(void) {

        for (PlotPointer plot = FirstPlot; plot != nullptr; plot = plot->next) {
            for (TreePointer tree= plot->FirstTree; tree != nullptr; tree = tree->next) {
                if (tree->isLiana) {
                    if (tree->attachedTree == nullptr && TestForLianaAttach(plot, tree))
                    DoLianaAttachement(plot, tree);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Code all in one place (in the correct order to compile).

```
struct Tree
{
    bool  isLiana;
    void* attachedTree;
    Tree* next;
};

using TreePointer = Tree*;

struct Plot
{
    TreePointer FirstTree;
    Plot*       next;
};

using PlotPointer = Plot*;

template<typename T>
struct NextIterator
{
    T* p;

    NextIterator():       p(nullptr) {}
    NextIterator(T* ptr): p(ptr)     {}

    NextIterator& operator++(){p = p->next;return *this;}

    T const& operator*() const  {return *p;}
    T&       operator*()        {return *p;}
    T const* operator->() const {return p;}
    T*       operator->()       {return p;}

    bool operator==(NextIterator const& rhs) const {return p == rhs.p;}
    bool operator!=(NextIterator const& rhs) const {return p != rhs.p;}
};

template<typename T>
NextIterator<T> make_NextIterator(T* val)   {return NextIterator<T>(val);}
template<typename T>
NextIterator<T> make_NextIterator()         {return NextIterator<T>{};}

NextIterator<Plot> begin(PlotPointer ptr)  {return make_NextIterator(ptr);}
NextIterator<Plot> end(PlotPointer)        {return make_NextIterator<Plot>();}

NextIterator<Tree> begin(TreePointer ptr)  {return make_NextIterator(ptr);}
NextIterator<Tree> end(TreePointer)        {return make_NextIterator<Tree>();}

bool TestForLianaAttach(PlotPointer, TreePointer);
void DoLianaAttachement(PlotPointer, TreePointer);

PlotPointer FirstPlot;

void DoLianaRange(void) {

        for(auto& plot: FirstPlot) {
            for(auto& tree: plot.FirstTree) {
                if (tree.isLiana) {
                    if (tree.attachedTree == nullptr && TestForLianaAttach(&plot, &tree))
                    DoLianaAttachement(&plot, &tree);
                }
            }
        }
}
void DoLiana(void) {

    PlotPointer plot;
    TreePointer tree;

        plot = FirstPlot;
        while (plot != nullptr) {
            tree = plot->FirstTree;
            while (tree != nullptr) {
                if (tree->isLiana) {
                    if (tree->attachedTree == nullptr && TestForLianaAttach(plot, tree))
                    DoLianaAttachement(plot, tree);
                }
                tree = tree->next;
            }
            plot = plot->next;
        }
}
```

Comment: `NextIterator` should be [DefaultConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultConstructible), which is as easy as putting ` = nullptr` in the current constructor's argument list. The end iterator can then just be `{}`

Comment: @Caleth: If you want to make `NextIterator` match the Iterator `Concept`. The range based for does not require that types be iterators.

Comment: It also gets rid of the ugly `make_NextIterator(static_cast<Tree*>(nullptr))`

Comment: Actually, `make_NextIterator` seems to be more trouble than it is worth. `NextIterator<Plot> begin(PlotPointer ptr)  {return ptr;} NextIterator<Plot> end(PlotPointer )  {return nullptr; }` do better

Comment: @Caleth But it fits a nice pattern (started by the standard). So yes the code is a bit cumbersome to write initially, but it provides mental clues and adds to the documentation of what is expected.

Comment: It fits a pattern of providing a place for argument deduction (and in the case of `shared_ptr`, optimising allocations). You are not deducing arguments here.

Comment: Look at `make_pair()`, `make_tuple()` it is the same pattern.

Comment: Yes, which are replaced by C++17's [deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) for `std::pair` and `std::tuple`

Comment: Even if you were defining a trait `is_intrusive_list<T>` (inheriting `std::true_type` if `T* next` is a member of `T` and `std::false_type` otherwise), then you might write a `template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<is_intrusive_list_v<T>, NextIterator<T>> begin(T * ptr);`, you still don't need argument deduction, as it's already known

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on [Serge Ballesta's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609854/range-based-for-loop-for-linked-list#comment92154294_52609854), you could immediately use vanilla `for` loops here, replacing the `while` loops. So your sample code will become:

```
void DoLiana(void) {

    for (PlotPointer plot = FirstPlot; plot; plot = plot->next) { 
        for (TreePointer tree = plot->FirstTree; tree; tree = tree->next) {
            if (tree->isLiana && !tree->attachedTree && TestForLianaAttach(plot, tree)) {
                DoLianaAttachement(plot, tree);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This shortens the code, and adds locality and perhaps readability. And also maintains compatibility with C, if this is an advantage.